# django allauth display all error messages

Tags: django, django-allauth

Is there a way to display all error messages in a customized login.html template using django with allauth? I do it with:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        {{ error|escape }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% for error in form.non_fields_errors %}
    {{ error|escape }}
{% endfor %}
```

But the error "Too many failed login attempts. Try again later." is not displayed with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

To display all messages use this:

```
<ul class="errorlist">
{% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
    <li>{% if key != '__all__' %}{{ key }} {% endif %}{{ value }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```